# Spring: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException?

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, spring-data, jodatime

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value did not match expected type. [java.util.Date (n/a)]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

Here is my query method in my repository:

```
 @Query("SELECT COUNT(entity) FROM Person entity WHERE trunc(entity.date) BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime")
 int getPersonBetweenDates(@Param("startTime") DateTime var1, @Param("endTime") DateTime var2);
```

And my implementation in component:

```
 int totalPersons = personRepo.getPersonBetweenDates(new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay(), DateTime.now());
```

Why am I getting this error? It seems that the two **DateTime** parameters in the implementation match those in my method?

Comment: Use `java.util.Date` instead of joda `DateTime` in `getPersonBetweenDates` method. You can use `toDate` method to convert joda's `DateTime` to `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Can you please post edited code? I am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Parameter value did not match expected type. [java.util.Date (n/a)];
```

Instead of using joda's `DateTime` in method parameters, use `java.util.Date`, Like following:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(entity) FROM Person entity WHERE trunc(entity.date) BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime")
int getPersonBetweenDates(@Param("startTime") Date var1, @Param("endTime") Date var2);
```

Then in your client code, if you have some `DateTime` instances, you can use `toDate` method to convert the `DateTime` into a `Date`:

```
personRepo.getPersonBetweenDates(new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate(), DateTime.now().toDate());
```